# Updating table view in a different controller when inserting/deleting entries in Core Data

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview, core-data

I am recently working on the Core Data project. There are two views: one of them is a form for user to fill in, then insert the entry via core data to a sqlite DB; another view is for displaying inserted entries and allow user to delete any of them.

I replicated the code for inserting/deleting entries from the Navigation-based Application project. Everything works fine if the user only perform insertion or deletion solely. However, when the two operations interleave, problems arise...

For instance:
1) A user inserts "Apple", "Orange" and "Grape" using the form. The table shows the data correctly.
2) The user then removes the entry "Orange". The table still looks good.
3) After that, the user inserts a new entry "Pear". The table is then messed up. The entry "Orange" comes up on the table again...

I monitored the sqlite DB throughout the whole testing process, everything works perfectly. The only problem is that the table is messed up.

I am suspecting that the error is caused because of the fact that the table data source is not updated. As a row is added/removed according to the indexPath, if the new entry shares the same indexPath with the old entry and the table data is not up to date, then it appears that the old entry is reinserted.

However I have no idea why the table data is not up to date. The insert/delete operation are performed under the same Managed Context.

This has been bothering me for a while, and I don't really have too much knowledge on core data. I really hope to hear any advices to get it sorted. Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicions are correct.

The *easiest* way to get what you want is to use an NSFetchedResultsController and it's delegate.

If you create a dummy project in Xcode make a navigation-based application and make sure use Core Data for storage is checked.

the area after

```
#pragma mark Fetched results controller delegate
```

in RootViewController.m will show you how to keep your UITableView updated when the model changes.